# How to create a tree structure with Space using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like below structure;

```
public class ListDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the list data is storing in below format

[image]

I want to filter this by below format with space. Not required a hierarchical list; Only required simple list with spaces

[image]

Comment: So you want to indent every "node" from it's parents. What have you tried?

Comment: @Zohar Peled Yes; I need every node from its parents with a space added before the Text.

Comment: This is a recursive build, you have to check if element.Any(child) (is parent, open new li)  , you have to check if a parent got childs to build it i think

Comment: You need to show some effort...

Comment: @Pradees - Could you please post the code that you've already written to do what you want? If you haven't written any then please delete the question and come back when you have tried to write the code.

Comment: Also, could you make sure that your sample data matches your desired output? Ideally you'd post your sample data as **valid C# code**.

Comment: Why does your sample result not match your sample input?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way of doing it. Maybe not the best but I'm sure someone can chime in and give a better suggestion on recursion.

```
var list = new List<ListDTO>()
{
    new ListDTO() { ID = 1, ParentID = 0, Name = "Name 1" },
    new ListDTO() { ID = 2, ParentID = 0, Name = "Name 2" },
    new ListDTO() { ID = 3, ParentID = 2, Name = "Name 11111" },
    new ListDTO() { ID = 4, ParentID = 3, Name = "Name 33333" }
};

Func<ListDTO, string, string> returnIdentatiton = null;
returnIdentatiton = (dto, identation) =>
{
    if (dto.ParentID == 0)
        return identation + string.Empty;
    else
        return returnIdentatiton(list.First(d => d.ID == dto.ParentID), identation + " ");
};

list.ForEach(l =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(returnIdentatiton(l, string.Empty) + l.Name);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `returnIndentation`? Why not just use a local function?

Comment: @NetMage What would I gain with local function?